# Git and GitHub CLI clone or push not working

Tags: git, github, openssl, github-for-windows

```
Cloning into '-'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/NazmusSayad/-.git/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443
exit status 128
```

If I push or clone anything this is't working. This is showing this error.
But if I relogin git with `gh auth login` then it is working but after reopening shell again not working.

**NB:** Git and GitHub CLI version are latest.

Comment: Are you using an antivirus, firewall, or proxy other than the Windows default?

Comment: no... But after enabling my router UPNP it is working prefectly. then i try disable UPNP but still working